# ApiController receives null in POST

Tags: json, webforms, asp.net-apicontroller

You'd think: how hard can this be? Well, Quite it seems.

jQuery running:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/api/TEST",
            data: {"":{close:true, user: "<%: uuid %>" }},
            success: null,
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

I am using asp.net webforms with the ApiContoller trying to post some simple data.

```
public class TESTController : ApiController {
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id) {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value) {
        string k = ";;";


    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value) {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id) {
    }
}
```

the POST method gets called, but the value is always null. I've tried changing the data in the ajax post without the empty quotes before it, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently after browsing through blogs for hours this is all you need to do / edit in the above example:

```
public string Post(tester test) {
    string k = ";;";

    return k;
}
```

add a class

```
public class tester {
    public string user { get; set; }
    public bool close { get; set; }
}
```

and change the AJAX to

```
    var value = {close:true, user: "<%: uuid %>" };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/api/TEST/",
        data: JSON.stringify(value)
    }).done(function(msg) {
        alert("done"+msg); 
    });
```